# In BIgQuery, how do I force a window to end at the current row when using a RANGE BETWEEN?

Tags: google-bigquery, windowing

In BigQuery, I have a table with a date field called `date`, and another row called `hit`.  Many rows can share the same `date`, but `date` + `hit` is unique.

| Row | Date | Source | Hit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/24 | google | 1 |
| 2 | 1/1/24 | NULL | 2 |
| 3 | 1/2/24 | facebook | 3 |
| 4 | 1/2/24 | NULL | 4 |
| 5 | 1/2/24 | twitter | 5 |
| 6 | 1/2/24 | NULL | 6 |
| 7 | 1/2/24 | bing | 7 |
| 8 | 1/31/24 | NULL | 8 |
| 9 | 2/10/24 | instagram | 9 |
| 10 | 2/10/24 | NULL | 10 |

I want to create a window that looks back 30 days but ends on the current row when ordered by date and hit.  With a `RANGE BETWEEN` clause you can only order by one value.

By design, it seems like `ORDER BY date RANGE BETWEEN 30 AND CURRENT ROW` will create a window that ends on all rows that match the current row's date, including those in the future.

For instance, observe the results of `lastNonDirect` for rows 5 and 6. I expect it to be 'twitter', however, it returns 'bing', since the date for row 5 and 6 is the same as row 7, and it chooses 7 as the `LAST_VALUE`.

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT 
  1 as origOrder, DATE '2024-01-01' as Date, 'google' as Source, 1 as Hit, 'google' as lastNonDirectClick, 'google' as currentCode UNION ALL
SELECT 
  2, DATE '2024-01-01', NULL, 2, 'google', 'google' UNION ALL
SELECT 
  3, DATE '2024-01-02', 'facebook', 3, 'facebook', 'bing' UNION ALL
SELECT 
  4, DATE '2024-01-02', NULL, 4,'facebook','bing' UNION ALL
SELECT 
5 ,DATE '2024-01-02','twitter',5,'twitter','bing' UNION ALL
SELECT 
6 ,DATE '2024-01-02',NULL ,6,'twitter','bing' UNION ALL
SELECT 
7 ,DATE '2024-01-02','bing',7,'bing','bing' UNION ALL
SELECT 
8 ,DATE '2024-01-31',NULL ,8,'bing','bing' UNION ALL
SELECT 
9 ,DATE '2024-02-10' ,'instagram',9,'instagram' ,'instagram' UNION ALL
SELECT 
10 ,DATE '2024-02-10',NULL ,10,'instagram' ,'instagram')
  ########################################################################################
SELECT
  origOrder,
  Date,
  SOURCE,
  Hit,
  LAST_VALUE(SOURCE IGNORE NULLS) OVER(
    ORDER BY
      UNIX_DATE(date) 
    RANGE BETWEEN
       30 PRECEDING
       AND CURRENT ROW) AS lastNonDirect
FROM
  t1
ORDER BY
  origOrder
```

Results:

| origOrder | Date | SOURCE | Hit | lastNonDirect |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-01-01 | google | 1 | google |
| 2 | 2024-01-01 |  | 2 | google |
| 3 | 2024-01-02 | facebook | 3 | bing |
| 4 | 2024-01-02 |  | 4 | bing |
| 5 | 2024-01-02 | twitter | 5 | bing |
| 6 | 2024-01-02 |  | 6 | bing |
| 7 | 2024-01-02 | bing | 7 | bing |
| 8 | 2024-01-31 |  | 8 | bing |
| 9 | 2024-02-10 | instagram | 9 | instagram |
| 10 | 2024-02-10 |  | 10 | instagram |

I attempted to be creative with the ORDER BY:

`LAST_VALUE(source) OVER(ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(date) + hit / 100000)`

But this won't work if my current hit number is greater than the hit I expect to get 30 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

An option can be convert the date to number using the format `%Y%m%d` that will keep the expected order and then add with the hit:

```sql
SELECT
  origOrder,
  Date,
  SOURCE,
  Hit,
  LAST_VALUE(SOURCE IGNORE NULLS) OVER(
    ORDER BY
      (CAST(FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', date) AS INT64) * 10000) + hit
    RANGE BETWEEN
       30 PRECEDING
       AND CURRENT ROW) AS lastNonDirect,
  (CAST(FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', date) AS INT64) * 10000) + hit
FROM
  t1
ORDER BY
  origOrder
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @DamiãoMartins.  I believe your solution would have an issue with the earliest window boarder.  If I am on a row with hit number 10, and the earliest reference is 30 days ago at hit number 4, it will be out of range.  Consider this dataset:

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT 
  1 as origOrder, DATE '2024-01-01' as Date, 'google' as Source, 1 as Hit, 'google' as lastNonDirectClick, 'google' as currentCode UNION ALL
SELECT 
10 ,DATE '2024-01-30',NULL ,10,'instagram' ,'instagram')
 ```